# Python bindings for Active Accessibility Windows 8?

Tags: python, windows-7, windows-8, accessibility, accessibility-api

I had to re-tweak and re-build pyAA (Python bindings for Microsoft Active Accessibility) on windows 7 and now it looks like I will have to migrate this to windows 8. I'm hoping I don't have to re-compile the bindings again!

Anybody know if there is a big difference (from the developer standpoint) for Microsoft Active Accessibility between Windows versions of Windows version 8?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recompile and see what happens :-D

Comment: Curious, what sort of things did you need to tweak? As far as I know, the underlying Win32 API and COM interfaces of MSAA have not changed since they were published back in 98ish or so. The usual issue you have to deal with with a new OS is the UI itself changing: eg. code that used MSAA to interact with the start menu won't work since there's no longer a Start menu...